# Python lxml won't install on the proper platform

Tags: python, pip, lxml, python-3.4, python-wheel

I have the following configuration:

> - Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit
> - Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:45:13) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> - pip 1.5.6
> - I do not have access to internet
> - I am not an administrator on my Windows system

I am trying to install **lxml library** on my Python. I have downloaded both **"lxml-4.0.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl"** and **"lxml-4.0.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl"** from *https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml.*

When I execute the following commands it throws the same error below:

```
pip install lxml-4.0.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl  
Error => lxml-4.0.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.  

pip install lxml-4.0.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl  
Error => lxml-4.0.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I cannot install from source because I do not have the required compiler on my system.

Does anyone know how can it be possible that none of Windows binaries made for Python 3.4 can install on my configuration ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: First, upgrade pip and setuptools: `pip install -U pip setuptools`. The current version of `pip` is 9.0.1!

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast. As I said, I am not administrator on my system and I do not have access to internet I am behind a corporate proxy server which only works in Firefox using a credential page. So I am afraid I cannot upgrade anything as pip will not be able to access internet.